# UICollectionView vertically Centred

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` object of size (320,500).

I need a to create the `UICollectionView` in such a way that contents are vertically centred. Means if total size of the content is (100,100) then the cells should drawing itself in a rect (0,200):(320,300). that is 50 above and 50 below the vertical centre at 250.

Problem is The number of cells and size of cells is decided only at runtime. For example if the text with in the cell can be 1 line is of size ~ (100,50) . If it is 4 lines size will be ~ (100,200). So it is only after I have run `collectionView:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` for the last cell that I can determine what should be starting position for first cell.

Any starting suggestion how I should approach this problem. Even if I subclass `Flowlayout` how will I know the position of the first cell before I draw the last one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I did it was by fetching the layout attributes of the last element in collection view and then deciding the contentInsets for the view. The problem it has is that the change in inset is not smooth since there is no animation but other wise it works.

```
-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {

  NSArray* array = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* att = [array lastObject];
    if (att){
        CGFloat lastY = att.frame.origin.y + att.frame.size.height;
        CGFloat diff = self.collectionView.frame.size.height - lastY;

        if (diff > 0){
            UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(diff/2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            self.collectionView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use insetForSectionAtIndex delegate method to center cells:

```
#pragma mark collection view cell paddings

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

  float leftInset = (self.view.frame.size.width - (COUNT_OF_CELL*WIDTH_OF_CELL + COUNT_OF_CELL-1 * SPACE_BETWEEN_CELLS)) / 2;

  return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftInset, 0, 0); // top, left, bottom, right

}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
  return 8;  // this is SPACE_BETWEEN_CELLS
}
```

You must change the COUNT_OF_CELL (this is count of your array), WIDTH_OF_CELL,SPACE_BETWEEN_CELLS and it will work as you wish

Comment: I need to set bottom and top insets not left right, I need to centre the view in middle of the screen vertically not horizontally