# how to use center vertically cells in collection view in paging mode in swift 4?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4, uicollectionviewlayout

I read 
[How to vertically center UICollectionView content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961616/how-to-vertically-center-uicollectionview-content)
 But when I used the codes here

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

let navBarHeight       = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
let collectionViewHeight = (self.collectionView?.frame.height)! - navBarHeight!
let itemsHeight        = self.collectionView?.contentSize.height

let topInset = ( collectionViewHeight - itemsHeight! ) / 4

return UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset ,0, 0 , 0)
}
```

But when scrolling collection view this will show incorrect form 
so here is my codes because my collection view cells are square and equal to screen width

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    showImagesCV.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)
    if let flowLayout = showImagesCV.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        cellWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        cellHeight = cellWidth //yourCellHeight = cellWidth if u want square cell
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        }
    }
  }
}

extension showImagesViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
  }
}
```

I want the spacing between cells be 0 and each cell that is showing (current page (because the collection view is in paging mode)) be the center of the screen 
[image: here is the problem in the photo]

Comment: some representation of what you want VS what you are getting would be helpful

Comment: so you mean you need more codes ?

Comment: no, some visual representation. Like screen shots

Comment: ok wait please I will update my question

Comment: as you can see here the collection view cell is not in the center of the screen @ibnetariq

Comment: your are trying to display vertical collectionView with paging. And you want to display one cell at a time, which should be centred. Is that right?

Comment: yes thats right @ibnetariq

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi I have checked ibnetariq's answer and seem like it works as what you want. Can you tell me what is problem from his answer? Maybe I can help you.

Comment: I used this method but when I scroll collection view the next cell will again at the wrong place if you have a team viewer and enough time I can show you with that

Comment: Sure, give me your contact.

Comment: ok please wait I will give the number here

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi It's better if you have skype, give me and i will add you

Comment: I don't have Skype But I have slack and also apple massages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169217/discussion-between-saeed-rahmatolahi-and-trungduc).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961616/how-to-vertically-center-uicollectionview-content) you mentioned and using, that is to centre the whole section not individual cells. Some of your code might be invalid(needs to be redone).

First and most important, set the constraints of your `collectionView` for full screen. Remember to take safeAre/TopGuide into account, this will make sure that collection view is below the navigation bar if there is one.

This will make sure that your collectionView is up to date

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

Dump/comment below code and set insets to (0,0,0,0) in inspector of collectionView in story board. In same inspector change Min Spacing to 0 for cells and for line, both.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

     let navBarHeight       = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
     let collectionViewHeight = (self.collectionView?.frame.height)! - navBarHeight!
     let itemsHeight        = self.collectionView?.contentSize.height

     let topInset = ( collectionViewHeight - itemsHeight! ) / 4

     return UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset ,0, 0 , 0)
}
```

Also remove/comment below code

```
 showImagesCV.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)
    if let flowLayout = showImagesCV.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        cellWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        cellHeight = cellWidth //yourCellHeight = cellWidth if u want square cell
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        }
    }
```

Now change your `sizeForItemAt` like this.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return collectionView.frame.size
  }
```

**UICollectionViewCell**
Now in your collectionView cell, make sure that your image view is 1:1 and in centre. Also handle constraints of your other UI components.

PS : This is easy approach, other would be to write custom flowLayout

Comment: that's not work as I expected the cells won't equal width to screen and from left and right there is little space and also the problem is that when I want to scroll collection view the problem is that the collection view will scroll But not going to the next cell it will going to the next2 cells(one more)

Comment: 1 : Make sure that paging is enabled
2 : Very first cell which appears  , is correct? I mean centre vertically centre aligned ?
3: After scroll(next 2), cell is in correct position ? Centred vertically ?

Comment: and also when I scroll collection view the next cell won't be in the center of the screen @ibnetariq

Comment: yes paging is enabled if you have some times I can show you with team viewer or taking photo or video and put the link of that to show you what exactly happen when I used these codes

Comment: in office, can't use team viewer. But screen shots are good idea.

Comment: I just ran the code and its working prefect.Never shared code on SO, let me figure out how. And you can do the rest.

Comment: ok here is the link of the picture that when I run the collection view https://ufile.io/5kpvh and here is the picture that when I scroll collection view https://ufile.io/yqxu6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168700/discussion-between-saeed-rahmatolahi-and-ibnetariq).

Comment: Click on the link  at top of your comment here continue this discussion in chat

Comment: sorry for delay now I am here in discussion part please help me

Comment: did you see my last message ?