# Centering UICollectionView focused row on tvOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I have a `UICollectionView` in my tvOS application populated with several `UICollectionViewCell`s, which in turn, contain a `UICollectionView` with items of their own inside.

The container `UICollectionView` scrolls vertically, whilst the inner `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally. Focus is disabled for the top level `UICollectionViewCell`s, and is passed into the items within the inner `UICollectionView`.

What it looks like, resembles this:

```
-------------------
|                 |
| --------------- |
| | xxxx xxxx xx| |
| | xxxx xxxx xx| |
| --------------- |
|                 |
| --------------- |
| | xxxx xxxx xx| |
| | xxxx xxxx xx| |
| --------------- |
|                 |
-------------------
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is when focus occurs on a row that is below the vertical centerline of the `UICollectionView`, the row should be vertically centered in the `UICollectionView`.

```
Before centering vertically
-------------------
| 1xxx xxxx xxxx x|
| 1xxx xxxx xxxx x|
|                 |
| 2xxx xxxx xxxx x|
| 2xxx xxxx xxxx x|
|                 |
| 3xxx xxxx xxxx x| <-
| 3xxx xxxx xxxx x| <-
|                 |
| 4xxx xxxx xxxx x|
-------------------
```

=

```
After centering vertically
-------------------
|                 |
| 2xxx xxxx xxxx x|
| 2xxx xxxx xxxx x|
|                 |
| 3xxx xxxx xxxx x|
| 3xxx xxxx xxxx x|
|                 |
| 4xxx xxxx xxxx x|
| 4xxx xxxx xxxx x|
|                 |
-------------------
```

Does anyone have a comment/suggestion on how I could achieve this?

**Edit:** Based on another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961616/how-to-vertically-center-uicollectionview-content), I have tried to implement the following `UICollectionViewDelegate` function, but it does not seem to work for me:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if let indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath,
            let _ = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            collectionView.contentInset.top = max((collectionView.frame.height - collectionView.contentSize.height) / 2, 0)
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** After some trial and error leading from the suggested answer below, I've gotten it to work with the following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if let indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath {
            collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
                self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: ...............and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @fuzz I've tried the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961616/how-to-vertically-center-uicollectionview-content, but they didn't seem to work for me? Have edited my original question with the sample code I've tried.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: @fuzz, ah, what I meant was, the focused row was still not being centered in the screen somehow.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://rolandleth.com/uicollectionview-snap-scrolling-and-pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scrollToItemAtIndexPath method like this :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath,
        let _ = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: 
         .centeredVertically, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

Some how you will have to extract the indexPath from the cell, using the accessiblity properties or something else, than you can scroll to that indexPath like this :

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let nextCell = context.nextFocusedView as? ScrumCollectionViewCell {
        let index = Int(nextCell.accessibilityHint!)!
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) { // 2
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that, but it does not seem to help; the cell is still not being centered vertically, strangely enough.

Comment: After some trial and error, I've gotten it to work by extending this answer, to which I will post my completed code in my original question. Marking this as the answer.

Comment: I have also found a solution to this, i am editing my answer.